# Best way to make new groups mailinglists by default

Tags: groups, forms, ui

I wonder how I may preset the mailinglist group type checkbox in group's edit form for new groups.

From a quick glance to code and db I assume that the is_default field in the db is not used here (have tried also).

So how could I do if I want to avoid a client side/js hack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a custom extension as explained [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) or using an existing one and implementing `hook_civicrm_buildForm`

**Updated**

```
function myextension_civicrm_buildForm( $formName, &$form ) {
  if ("CRM_Group_Form_Edit" == $formName) {
    if ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
      $defaults = array ("group_type[2]" => true);
      $form->setDefaults($defaults);
    }
  }
}
```

That will make the *Mailing list* checkbox checked by default.

Comment: works like a charm, thx

Comment: This leads to checked ćheckbox when editing existing groups too – which looks like if a non-mailinglist were a mailinglist.

Comment: Re-accepted :) Thanks a load!